# If I click the submit button fast enough it sends out multiple of the same mails, how do I fix this?

Tags: php

If I click the submit button fast enough it will send 1 or 2 more e-mails than I want (which is obviously one). I don't want this to happen, would anyone no a solution to this?

I already tried disabling the button after 1 click, but this also made it so it didn't send mails.

````
<body>
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
        <div class="mail">
Naam:<br>
              <input class="naam" type="text" name="naam" maxlength="40" required="required" placeholder="Vul hier je volledige naam in." /> *<br /><br />
Mail:<br>
              <textarea class="text" name="mail" placeholder="Klik hier om een mail te schrijven." rows="10"></textarea><br /><br />
              <input type="submit" name="verzend" value="Verzend de gegevens" />
        </div>
</form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["verzend"]))
{
$to = "caelan2@caelanvaneijnsbergen.infdlw.nl";
$subject = $_POST["naam"].' mailt vanaf de website';
$txt = $_POST["mail"];
mail($to,$subject,$txt);
}
?>```
````

Comment: Why would you click it more then once?

Comment: Use some JavaScript to disable the button on click and then submit. If you tried this then show us how because it should work as before.

Comment: Ideally you would require the form be completed in order to send an email, you would then clear the form after it has been clicked. This would stop someone repeatedly clicking the button as they would first need to re-fill out the form.

Comment: The user can disable javascript and send spam emails. Then what? You require a server solution (PHP)

Answer (score 0):

You can set onclick element on button and add id to the form. On click disable the button in Javascript and submit the form via form id in javascript. 
This way the button is surely not clickable twice and form is submitted.
See below.

```
    <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="myForm">
<div class="mail">
Naam:<br>
      <input class="naam" type="text" name="naam" maxlength="40"  placeholder="Vul hier je volledige naam in." /> *<br /><br />
Mail:<br>
      <textarea class="text" name="mail" placeholder="Klik hier om een mail te schrijven." rows="10"></textarea><br /><br />
      <input onclick="disable(event, this);" name="verzend" value="Verzend de gegevens" />
</div>
</form>

<script>

    function disable(event, button) {
        event.preventDefault();
        button.disabled = true;    
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I put it inside my code, but I can't get it working, am I supposed to get rid of the php like above? if that's the case how do I send it to my own mail?

Comment: No you are not supposed to get rid of your php. I just used an example in the answer. You might be missing something out if its not working please share more information how did you integrate it in your code.

Comment: I also edited my code about to get the event parameter to disable default submit action. Might be the case for you.